# React Native : textShadow not rendering well on sides

Tags: react-native, shadow, react-native-text

I have troubles to use textShadow propriety as expected. Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

class Test extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
         <Text style={}>Some textooo</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30, 
    fontWeight: '900', 
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)', 
    textShadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    textShadowRadius: 10,
}

 
})

export default Test
```

Here is how it renders :

[Text with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm3Ue.png)

As you can notice, shadow is cut at the beginning and at the end of the text...

**Does anyone knows how to avoid this?** (Without adding " " in the string to render)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: show full screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of your code https://snack.expo.io/@jsfit/text-shadow seems good to me

[image]

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for your help. I ran your code and I still have the same problem, if your zoom closely on the last "o" you will see the shadow is cut... Maybe what I ask is not possible?

Comment: on which device are you checking. because iPhone and android both are different in nature and the iPhone has some color problem

Comment: I check on both Android and iPhone (both on physical devices not on emulators). That is strange because it does not render the same for me... Your rendering is exactly what I expect...

Comment: so that means some other part of code is making the problem, check for that by commenting out unrelated code

Answer (score 1):

Adding empty space at the end seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

give Text component width and height then align the text

```
textAlign: 'center',
textAlignVertical: 'center'
```

```
  text: {
    fontSize: 30, 
    fontWeight: '900', 
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)', 
    textShadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    textShadowRadius: 10,

    //add this styles
    width:100,
    height: 100,
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center'
}
```